# Deploying PubSub emulator to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm new to Kubernetes and appreciate some direction.
I'm setting up a testing environment in Kubernetes via helm charts. One testing dependency is PubSub. I want to spin up a PubSub emulator container in Kubernetes, I know I can use the official gCloud image with the `emulators` tag from here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-docker
but after that is deployed, I need to run a command to start the emulator as described here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/pubsub/start

Is there a way to do this on container startup?